# Unit Testing Java Code - Mocking a non-static method of a different class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock, jmockit

```
public class First {

    public First(){
    }

    public String doSecond(){
        Second second = new Second();
        return second.doJob();
    }
}

class Second {

    public String doJob(){
        return "Do Something";
    }
}
```

Here I want to test the method "doSecond()" of class "First". For the same, I want to mock the method "doJob" of class "Second".

I know that I can create a mocked instance of class "Second" using the code below.

```
Second sec = mock(Second.class);
when(sec.doJob()).thenReturn("Stubbed Second");
```

But I cannot relate this mocked instance with class "First" as of the current code.
**Without refactoring** the source code, is there any way by which i can achieve the requirement.
Please help.

Comment: This would be a heck of a lot easier to follow if the two methods had different names. I thought you were trying to mock the method under test for a minute.

Comment: On a separate note, if `First.doSecond` is really as simple as it's portrayed here, you probably shouldn't be testing it anyway, because you're just testing `Second.doSecond` by proxy.

Comment: ok, how can i solve it. can you please post the solution as answer.
In the actual scenario, method names are different.

Comment: @ChrisHayes This is just a small example to explain the real problem I am facing now. Please help.

Comment: [Dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) handles this sort of scenario well. I'd recommend reading up on it and deciding whether it's right for your project.

Comment: just to confirm, I can test the same without making any changes in the code using dependency injection right?

Comment: @NidhinJoseph no you need to change the code to support dependency injection.  See my answer for how to do it without any source changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's tricky to mock an instance that you create inside of a method, but it's possible.

Using PowerMock, you can accomplish this with the [`PowerMock.expectNew()`](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor) method:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(First.class)
public class StackOverflowTest {

    @Test
    public void testFirst() throws Exception {
        Second secondMock = EasyMock.createMock(Second.class);
        PowerMock.expectNew(Second.class).andReturn(secondMock);
        expect(secondMock.doSecond()).andReturn("Mocked!!!");
        PowerMock.replay(secondMock, Second.class);
        String actual = new First().doSecond();
        PowerMock.verify(secondMock, Second.class);
        assertThat(actual, equalTo("Mocked!!!"));
    }

}
```

Effectively, PowerMock is proxying the creation of the new object and substituting whatever value we want when we invoke `doSecond()`.

So, it's *possible*.  However, this is a **terrible** practice to get into.

One typically wants to mock objects if they involve an outside concern, such as another layer (i.e. database, validation), or if the desired output is coming from other objects that are injected but are safe enough to consider tested.

If your method is capable of getting or retrieving data from a non-injectable source, you should not want to mock that out.

Considering that your method is simple and straightforward, you should really not need to do any mocks here at all.  But if you felt that you were forced to, you could do one of a few things:

- Create a factory for the creation of `Second`, and mock the results of the returning factory object with Mockito.
- Pass in an instance of `Second` to that method, and use Mockito as the mock instance.
- Declare it as a field (i.e. injected dependency), and use Mockito.

Comment: While changing the sourcecode is probably the best route.  The OP specifically asked for a solution that didn't require source changes.  I've been involved in many projects with a huge legacy codebase that had to be maintained and tested but without the time or budget to refactor the bad designs.  The powermock solution is the band-aid to fill that need.

Comment: Yes, but the time to write the tests is typically time enough to refactor to make them easier to test in some cases.  It seems very, very strange to me that one would want to mock the creation of a new instance instead of either injecting it or passing it in.

Comment: @Makoto The argument against mocking non-injected dependencies is very weak. Whether a dependency is injected or not should be irrelevant for the decision of whether to mock or not. What matters is whether the dependency falls inside or outside the "unit under test"; if it's outside, and you want to write a *unit* test with proper isolation, you would need to mock the dependency. For a real-world example, consider a class using the Apache Commons Email API: you would certainly want to mock the `Email` subclass in this case, even though it is normally instantiated rather than injected.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at powermock's ability to intercept calls to `new` and return mocks instead

https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor

This doesn't require changing any sourcecode.

here's the test code where we actually return a mock when First.doSecond() calls `new Second()`

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(First.class)
public class TestFirst {

@Test
public void mockSecond() throws Exception{
    Second mock = PowerMockito.mock(Second.class);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(Second.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mock);
    PowerMockito.when(mock.doSecond()).thenReturn("from mock");

    First first = new First();

    assertEquals("from mock",  first.doSecond());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here is how the test can be written with the JMockit mocking API, without any refactoring of the original code under test:

```
public class ExampleTest
{
    @Test
    public void firstShouldCallSecond(@Mocked final Second secondMock) {
        new NonStrictExpectations() {{
            secondMock.doJob(); result = "Mocked!!!";
        }};

        String actual = new First().doSecond();

        assertEquals("Mocked!!!", actual);
    }
}
```